# Django использует код css не полностью

Tags: html, css, django

Написал адаптацию для сайта в css, но django почему-то не полностью её использует. Если отдельно запускать html-код и css, то работает отлично(все пути прописаны правильно, django видит сам css и даже использует его, но наполовину)

Comment: Трудно ответить на этот вопрос слишком много причин может быть. Как вариант возможно Django видит не тот CSS файл. Возможно необходимо сделать manage.py collectstatic. Сравните свой CSS файл и тот который приходит в браузер от Django. И посмотрите какой HTML код генерирует Django присудствуют там те классы которые вы определили в CSS файле.

Comment: Вот сейчас посмотрел и в браузер почему-то передаётся не весь код из css, не все строчки видит

Comment: решил проблему сделав collectstatic, спасибо!